# Return List<T> as XML Response from WCF Service?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Operation that returns a List of Colors:

```
public List<Color> GetColors()
{
    List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
    colors.Add(new Color {Name = "Red", Code = 1});
    colors.Add(new Color {Name = "Blue", Code = 2});

    return colors;   
}
```

When I run this in the WCF Test Client, it works fine and I can see the array of colors, but what I would actually like is if it returned the XML Response and then I could set a `RichTextBox`'s Text to the contents of the xml.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the XML representation of the list return to the client my advice would be to serialize the list and return it as a string to the client.

Here is some code that can get you started. Haven't tested it but I think it might be easy for you to change.

```
public string GetColorsXmlRepresentation()
{
    var colors = new List<Color>();

    colors.Add(new Color {Name = "Red", Code = 1});
    colors.Add(new Color {Name = "Blue", Code = 2});

    return Serialize<List<Color>>(colors);
}


public string Serialize<T>(T instance)
{
    var data = new StringBuilder();
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(instance.GetType());

    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(data))
    {
       serializer.WriteObject(writer, instance);
       writer.Flush();

      return data.ToString();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This worked great.  What is all this stuff I read about IDispatchMessageInspector?

Comment: If you want to perform modifications on messages when they arrive or before they are sent you can use an extensibility mechanism of WCF called message inspectors. You can check more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx

Comment: What if I don't want to just return the plain xml, but I want to return it as a soap envelope?

Comment: -1: If you're going to serialize to XML, then why not return XML?

Comment: I misread the question. I though he wanted the XML representation of the list only. Not the entire SOAP message.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your WCF service to return XML, then make it return XML. If you want it to return `List<Color>`, then it should return `List<Color>`.

Comment: John, if I want to return the SOAP Envelope, do I have to build it manually?  I was thinking of using XElement to build the xml and return that.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: @Xai: no. WCF serializes your `List<Color>` for you.

Comment: @Sergio: in what way is this an opinion? It's a fact.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use open generics in WCF contracts. SOAP doesn't have any support for generics.

Comment: WCF != SOAP. WCF can also be REST, JSON or binary and probably a few others.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  When I run the WCFTest client that comes with Microsoft, I see a Formatted tab and and XML tab.  I basically want to view my results just like they appear in the xml tab, but in my own wpf application.

Comment: looks like he was talking about SOAP though!